# How to delete empty strings sandwiched by non-empty strings while fuse other empty ones?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

Sorry for the confusing title but describing the question within one line is a bit hard. So I have a list that looks like this:

```
['','','','A','','','B','','C','','D','','','']
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
['A','','','B','C','D']
```

Process: 
1. Remove any starting and ending empty string (those before A and after D).
2. Remove the single empty strings that are sandwiched by non-empty strings (like the ones between B & C and C & D). However, if there are more than 1 empty strings sandwiched, keep them (like those 2 between A & B).

Could someone help me out on this issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: more than 1 sandwiched? so if you have ['A', '', 'B'] you don't want to keep the single quote?

Comment: This doesn't cover all of the edge cases, but it should put you on the right track: `" ".join(['','','','A','','','B','','C','','D','','','']).strip().split(" ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. You could use `itertools.groupby` to identify runs of identical strings, and count how many appear in a row:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> seq = ['','','','A','','','B','','C','','D','','','']
>>> runs = [(c, len(list(g))) for c,g in itertools.groupby(seq)]
>>> runs
[('', 3), ('A', 1), ('', 2), ('B', 1), ('', 1), ('C', 1), ('', 1), ('D', 1), ('', 3)]
```

Then remove the first and last elements if they are empty strings:

```
>>> if runs[0][0] == '': runs = runs[1:]
...
>>> if runs[-1][0] == '': runs = runs[:-1]
...
>>> runs
[('A', 1), ('', 2), ('B', 1), ('', 1), ('C', 1), ('', 1), ('D', 1)]
```

Then remove any interior groups that are composed of one empty string:

```
>>> runs = [(char, count) for char, count in runs if not (char == '' and count == 1)]
>>> runs
[('A', 1), ('', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1)]
```

Then reconsitute the runs into a flat list.

```
>>> result = [char for char, count in runs for _ in range(count)]
>>> result
['A', '', '', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: This works! Just a quick question: after you get [('A', 1), ('', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1)], could you get all those interior groups that are composed of more than 1 empty string to be of 5 empty strings or any fixed number? Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps in that case you could do `result = [char for char, count in runs for _ in range(5 if char=='' and count > 1 else count)]`.

Comment: You're amazing! This helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer that won't work under all conditions, but will work if you can identify a character that *is not* present in the list.  The general idea is to join the list, strip, replace single runs of the element, and then split on the element:

***Setup***

```
L = ['', '', '', 'A', '', '', 'B', '', 'C', '', 'D', '', '', '']
import re
```

---

```
re.sub(r'(?<!@)@@(?!@)', r'@', '@'.join(L).strip('@')).split('@')
```

```
['A', '', '', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

---

Wrap it in a function and assert that the `el` element is valid:

```
def custom_stripper(L, el):
    """
    Strips empty elements from start/end of a list,
    and removes single empty whitespace runs

    Parameters
    ----------
    L: iterable, required
        The list to modify
    el: str, required
        An element found nowhere in the joined list

    Returns
    -------
    A properly formatted list
    """

    assert(el not in ''.join(L))
    rgx = r'(?<!{el}){el}{el}(?!{el})'.format(el=el)

    return re.sub(rgx, el, el.join(L).strip(el)).split(el)
```

```
>>> custom_stripper(L, '@')
['A', '', '', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> custom_stripper(L, 'A')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-7afa6741e503> in <module>()
----> 1 custom_stripper(L, 'A')

<ipython-input-158-606893c3fe1c> in custom_stripper(L, el)
     11     """
     12
---> 13     assert(el not in ''.join(L))
     14     rgx = r'(?<!{el}){el}{el}(?!{el})'.format(el=el)
     15

AssertionError:
```

---

To break this down:

```
>>> '@'.join(L).strip('@')
'A@@@B@@C@@D'

>>> re.sub(r'(?<!@)@@(?!@)', r'@', 'A@@@B@@C@@D')
'A@@@B@C@D'

>>> 'A@@@B@C@D'.split('@')
['A', '', '', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

---

***Regex Explanation***

The substitution is key, because it allows replacement of two `@` in a row (signifying a place in the list where only a single empty string existed).  However, you have to be careful that you don't replace two `@` in a row, inside another run of `@` (for example, if there were two empty strings in a row).  The key here is negative lookahead/lookbehind.

```
(?<!                     # Negative lookbehind
  @                      # Asserts string *does not* match @
)                        
@@                       # Matches @@
(?!                      # Negative lookahead
  @                      # Asserts string *does not* match @
)
```